# WP_Query is being reset after <header> tag (using chaining method)

Tags: wp-query

I'm creating a page template. In this page template I create a custom query.

**- page-recipes.php:**

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: Recepten - archief
 * chained with /archive-recipes.php
 * 
 */

$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');

/**
 * Create Query Arguments
 */

$taxedQueryArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'paged' => $paged,

);

global $wp_query;

query_posts( $taxedQueryArgs );

require_once( 'archive-recipes.php' );
?>
```

As you can see I require the 'archive-recipes.php' page. In this archive page I want to list the recipes by the arguments passed in the 'page-recipes.php' page template. Therefor I use this:

**- archive-recipes.php:**

```
<?php
/* first query call */
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($wp_query->query);
echo '</pre>';
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
/* second query call */
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($wp_query->query);
echo '</pre>';
?>

<?php

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    the_title(); 

endwhile; endif;

?>
```

But after the `<?php get_header(); ?>` tag my query gets reset. The first query call beneath `/* first query call */` in the example shows the query with my arguments from the `page-recipes.php` template, but the part with the `/* second query call */` displays the query of the page itself.

Comment: [DO NOT USE `query_posts`, use `new WP_Query` or `get_posts` instead](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Oké, so I created a new var in which I stored the new WP_Query and simply called this new variable on the 'second query call' place. This seems to be working, even with pagination.

Comment: Yet another instance that is proof why you should never ever use `query_posts`